# concurrency using node.js application

Tags: node.js, concurrency

This is my sample code for web-server which hosts a 100MB files and provide users link to download it. This application works for few download requests

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');   // The ExpressJS framework
var fs = require('fs');
var console = require('console');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/f1', function(req, res){
var filenameWithPath = __dirname+"/uploaded_files/f1";
res.setHeader("content-type", "binary");
console.log(filenameWithPath);
res.download(filenameWithPath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(data);
    });
  });

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.write('This is lift-downloadable app home page');
    res.end();
    });
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });
```

However when I run the concurrent test using script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd tmp
rm *
for i in `seq 1 20`;
do
  wget  https://lift-downloadable.mybluemix.net/f1 &
done
```

It actually downloads the files partially. The observations are :
1) It takes time to start the download and the download start delay increases when we increase number of concurrent threads.
2) So suppose 2 out of 15 of the download threads started downloading and when the 3rd one starts downloading the first two's download ends abruptly and following up all other threads also end abruptly after starting download. 3) Also I am not able to see the download size during file download. It always say something like 2MB out of unknown.

I have verified that download speed is quite good so network bandwidth is good and we do not see memory of cpu issue on the server hosting this application.

Can you please help.

Comment: step 1 is always "reduce your complexity to find the problem". Does it work with *just* express hosting your file for you, without morgan/cluster/etc? Cool, put one layer on top, retry. Continue until it no longer works, and then zoom in and debug further.

Comment: yes. the problem exists even with just express. I added cluster only to mitigate the delay issue. however did not see much difference. How do I add retry ?

Comment: Also how do I specify the file size during download. Currently during download it says something like: 2mb out of unknown file size.
This is what I have tried but it did not work.

      var stat = fs.statSync(filenameWithPath);
     res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Length": stat.size});

Comment: if it exists with just express, please update your post with the vastly simpler code, so people can reproduce (never just give answers in comments  to questions about clarification or code, work them into your post so that everyone else sees them when they look at the question)